# selenium browser launch by octopus

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser, selenium-chromedriver, octopus-deploy, octopus

We have implemented a CI CD pipeline using octopus, once any code change is checked in then our automation script gets picked up and launches chrome browser. It tries to maximize the browser before starting test case. However octopus is not able to maximize the browser. I have used Javascript executor and below maximize code as well.

driver.manage().window().maximize();

can we launch chrome broswer instance either in maximize mode or full screen mode without using above line or javascript executor?

Comment: @ DebanjanB, I am not getting any exception while executing  driver.manage().window().maximize();  this line gets executed and scipt moves to the next step but browser didn't maximized. As the broswer didn't get maximized some of the site button are overlapped. hence scripts fails at that button click step.